# Sorting data on column

Tags: pandas

How do I sort the dataframe based on the first column in an multiindexed column?

```
mypivot
                 url
status           200  301  302  304  404
ip
900.43.91.8        1    1    1  NaN    1
07.167.103.22    18  NaN  NaN  NaN    1
17.211.102.92    18  NaN  NaN  NaN    2
17.216.172.5     21  NaN  NaN  NaN    1
18.151.211.10    19  NaN  NaN  NaN    2
25.18.235.210    12  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
34.139.155.135   733    2  NaN  301   53
11.216.235.175    8  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7.228.106.211    18  NaN  NaN  NaN    1
2.104.61.135     18  NaN  NaN  NaN    1
9.58.151.168      2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6.249.67.53     NaN  NaN    1  NaN    2
6.249.67.66       1    2  NaN  NaN  NaN
6.249.67.79       1  NaN    1  NaN    1
9.37.224.70        1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6.110.226.29      1    1    1  NaN  NaN
```

The IP address 34.139.155.135 should be at top because it has maximum number for 200 status.

I have tried the following 3 statements but none of them are sorting on 200 status column.

```
mypivot.sort()
mypivot.sort(ascending=False)
mypivot.sort(ascending=False , axis=1)
```

The data types are:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 16 entries, 900.43.91.8 to 6.110.226.29
Data columns (total 5 columns):
(url, 200)    15 non-null float64
(url, 301)    4 non-null float64
(url, 302)    4 non-null float64
(url, 304)    1 non-null float64
(url, 404)    10 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(5)
```

And here are columns with levels.

```
In [85]: mypivot.columns
Out[85]:
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'url'], [200, 301, 302, 304, 404]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]],
           names=[None, u'status'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mypivot.sort([('url', 200)], ascending=False)
```